# Renaming print task URL of ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing

I have simple print task using ESRI javscript API `PrintParameters`, `PrintTemplate` and `printTask`. Its working fine. Its return URL like this:

```
http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/directories/arcgisoutput/Utilities/PrintingTools_GPServer/x_____x2Aoqp2xDc-wF9_eV5CU5-w..x_____x_ags_8e12cae972fe45ee848cc74d5e96178b.pdf.
```

But I need URL like this:

```
http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/directories/arcgisoutput/Utilities/PrintingTools_GPServer/{CurrentDateTime}.pdf
```

**format** : `CurrentDateTime = 20150806110602 (yyymmddhhmmss)`

It is possible?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the default Print Service can't do this. You may be able to do this via arcpy and a custom print tool. [You can see a sample here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Tutorial_Basic_web_map_printing_exporting_using_arcpy_mapping/0154000005z3000000/).